# LIBGDX screen capture gives me black or wrong result

Tags: android-activity, libgdx, opengl-es-2.0, game-engine, video-capture

I'm using [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Take-a-Screenshot) method to capture the screen in LIBGDX. Most of the time I get a black screen. When I do get something though it does not capture all the contents of the screen. I have a few scene2D tables that are not captured and some of the elements on the screen (like fonts) are flipped horizontally.

I've tried all the solutions on the internet on screen capturing but I only get a black screen, OR, with the above method, scarcely any result. Is there any chance I can capture LIBGDX screens (loaded with shaders) properly?

Comment: When and where are you calling this? Make sure you are not doing it between `glClear` and the last thing you render in the `render` method.

Comment: I have a ClickListener to a Scene2D ImageButton . Inside that click listener I call the method from the link above .

Comment: Thank you Tenfour. you can put that as the answer if you'd like it accepted. I put a flag in the click listener and now I check that flag at the end of the render method and it saves the screen capture. But the whole Image is flipped horizontally . Any idea why is that?